# Filter on length of arrays in a column containing arrays in Scala Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a schema for a DataFrame called "mydf" as follows:

```
root
|--properties
|  |-- arrayCol: array (nullable = true)
|  |  |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|  |  |  |-- unimportantElem1: string (nullable = true)
|  |  |  |-- unimportantElem2: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want to filter rows based on the "arrayCol" column having arrays with size (length of the array) equaling "s", and count the number of such rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydf filter(size($"properties.arrayCol") === 4) count
```

Here I am filtering rows to find all rows having arrays of size 4 in column arrayCol.

Note that the arrayCol is nested (properties.arrayCol) so it might help someone with the use case of filtering on nested columns. I got the answer while posting the question.